# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\Testing Tools\Appium\New folder\Android SDK;\build-tools'

Tags: android, appium

I am trying to run my first appium program but it throws this error:

> ENOENT, NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PATH:

```
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\Testing Tools\Appium\New folder\Android SDK without semicolon ';'.
```